# Reversing a stack from one class in another class

Tags: java, class, stack

I've been tasked with making a method in a separate class (an extension of the Stack util) that takes a stack and reverses it (i.e stack is [5, 7, 10] return [10, 7, 5]).

The TEST class was provided by the professor to use my separate class and its method to run these commands.

EDIT: Solution suggested by mwohlf implemented

Code:

Test class (provided by professor):

```
public class myStackReverseTEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int val;
        myStackReverse<Integer> stack = new myStackReverse<Integer>();
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
        stack.push(new Integer(5));
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
        stack.push(new Integer(10));
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
        stack.push(new Integer(7));
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
        stack.push(new Integer(10));
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
        val = stack.pop();
        System.out.println(stack.toString());
        System.out.println(stack.toStringReverse());
    }

}
```

My class with the method toStringReverse():

```
import java.util.*;

public class myStackReverse<E> extends Stack<E> {

    public String toStringReverse()
    {
        Stack<E> origStack = (Stack)this.clone();
        Stack<E> revStack = new Stack<E>();

        while (!origStack.isEmpty())
        {
            revStack.add(origStack.pop());
        }

        return revStack.toString();

    }
}
```

Side-note: There is a serialization error, and I was told to ignore it if I wanted to, as it wouldn't directly affect the outcome of the program when finished.

Comment: your spec, test code and your class is not consistent with each other.

Comment: So, in your method you're creating empty stacks each time... This can't be right

Comment: Note that you're creating a new `Stack` object in your reversing method and using that. It is of course always empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
import java.util.*;
class myStackReverse<E> extends Stack<E> {
    public String toStringReverse() {
        Stack<E> origStack = (Stack)this.clone();
        Stack<E> revStack = new Stack<E>();
        while (!origStack.isEmpty()) {
            revStack.add(origStack.pop());
        }
        return revStack.toString();
    }
}
```

or if you want to avoid the clone to use less memory (but more code):

```
class myStackReverse<E> extends Stack<E> {
    public String toStringReverse() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("[");
        if (this.size() > 0) {
            sb.append(this.get(this.size()-1));
        }
        for (int i = this.size()-2; i>=0; i--) {
            sb.append(", ");
            sb.append(this.get(i));
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add English to explain why your code answers the question.

Comment: as Sami Kuhmonen pointed out, the original code reverses the content of an empty new Stack Object, this code uses the original Stack which actually contains the elements

Comment: This code returns a stack with only the most recently added value in it (after 10 is added to the stack, it does a double [10] [10])

Comment: Updated the question to show what the new output is with your suggestions.

Comment: oops, sorry Matt, was to lazy to try it out... calling the pop on the Stack is not a good idea because it modifies the content, cloning to have a copy and call the pop on the copy seems to work...

Comment: After making a clone and rerunning, it works perfectly. Thank you kindly! Marking this as the answer with final edits.